# Unable to align react date pickers

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to display two datepickers in a single line.Next to each other.But they are not coming in single line instead they are coming one below another.
Below is my code.

```
<Datepicker selected={this.state.checkInDate} style={{display: 'inline-block'}} />

<Datepicker selected={this.state.checkOutDate} style={{display:'inline-block'}} />
```

It seems date picker is simply ignoring my style.

Comment: What you have tried so far, please provide the code?

Comment: Update your question with a complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is too simple. You could give us a bit more of code and info about which Datepicker you are using.

Aside from that, did you try to put them inside a flex container?

```
<div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <Datepicker selected={this.state.checkInDate} />
  <Datepicker selected={this.state.checkInDate} />
</div>
```